# Navigating to back from VisualForce page in SalesForce1

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have created VisualForce page. I wrote a script code to navigate back. It's working as expected in desk top but not in Salesforce1 iPad application. In Salesforce1 screen is empty.

Please find below code

```
if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && (sforce != null) ) {
  window.history.back(-1) ;
} else {
  window.location.href = '{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.view, Opportunity.Id)}';
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's known issue from Salesforce1 [link] https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5jeAAC.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

> You can use **back(​[refresh])** function.

It will navigates to the previous state that’s saved in the sforce.one history. It’s equivalent to clicking a browser’s Back button.
refresh is optional. By default, the page doesn’t refresh. Pass true to refresh the page if possible.